# urlconfig - It takes Default parameter, not the passing one

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

if I pass  http://127.0.0.1:8000/call/?p=3  and i print num in view.page it prints 1

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('call/',views.call),
    path('call/page<int:num>/',views.call),
]

if I pass 127.0.0.1:8000/call/?p=3 and it prints num 1 and not 3.

# View (in blog/views.py)
def page(request, num=1):
  print(num)   // 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?p=3` part is the [*querystring* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), not the *path*. Those parameters are stored in the [**`request.GET`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET), a dictionary-like object, except that a key can map to *multiple* parameters.

There is thus only *one* path:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('call/',views.call),
]
```

You then fetch it with [**`QueryDict.get(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.get), where we can provide a *default* parameter:

```
def page(request):
  print(request.GET.get('p', 1))
```

---

If you specify:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('call/',views.call),
    path('call/page<int:num>/',views.call),
]
```

then the URL to trigger the second path is `127.0.0.1:8000/call/page3`.